# C++ form unresponsive on start

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

i'm working on my first C++ project that requires a form and I've seemed to have gone in way over my head. largely I believe my issue has to do with that I'm not multi threading my form, but I'm unsure of the proper implementation. I was hoping someone could point out to me exactly where I've gone and made myself look like a muppet. (warning for the feint of heart, I used global variables to quickly create a proof of concept, once I have everything working more or less correctly I'll go back and properly protect everything)

*edit: I guess to clarify, it looks like the issue is that i execute everything in the main thread, its is possible to create a single new thread for the entire form or do i need to create a new thread for each individual control on the form?

Winmain.cpp

main function where I initialize the form and update the information on the form / refresh the form.

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    using namespace Interface;
    cooldowns ^ CDwin = gcnew cooldowns;
    CDwin->Show();
    CDwin->Location = Point(0,0);

    while (true)
    {
        CDwin->timer1->Text = timer1Duration.ToString();
        CDwin->timer1Progress->Value = timer1Value;
        CDwin->timer1->Refresh();
        CDwin->timer1Progress->Refresh();

        //collect info to populate CDwin values for next cycle
        //something tells me this sleep could be part of the problem?

        Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

form.h

```
#pragma once

namespace Interface {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::Threading;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for cooldowns
    /// </summary>
    public ref class cooldowns : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        cooldowns(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~cooldowns()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    public: System::Windows::Forms::ProgressBar^  timer1Progress;

    protected: 

    public: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  timer1;

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->timer1Progress = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ProgressBar());
            this->timer1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // timer1Progress
            // 
            this->timer1Progress->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Fuchsia;
            this->timer1Progress->Location = System::Drawing::Point(3, 12);
            this->timer1Progress->Maximum = 30000;
            this->timer1Progress->Name = L"timer1Progress";
            this->timer1Progress->Size = System::Drawing::Size(244, 18);
            this->timer1Progress->Style = System::Windows::Forms::ProgressBarStyle::Continuous;
            this->timer1Progress->TabIndex = 0;
            this->timer1Progress->Value = 10000;
            //
            //timer1
            //
            this->timer1->AutoSize = true;
            this->timer1->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::White;
            this->timer1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(253, 108);
            this->timer1->Name = L"Timer1";
            this->timer1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(34, 13);
            this->timer1->TabIndex = 9;
            this->timer1->Text = L"00.00";
            // 
            // cooldowns
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(64)), static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(64)), 
                static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(64)));
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(294, 138);
            this->Controls->Add(this->Timer1);;
            this->Controls->Add(this->timer1Progress);
            this->FormBorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::None;
            this->Name = L"cooldowns";
            this->StartPosition = System::Windows::Forms::FormStartPosition::Manual;
            this->Text = L"cooldowns";
            this->TopMost = true;
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &cooldowns::cooldowns_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion

private: System::Void cooldowns_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

         }
};
}
```

edit after a lot of trial and error the issue seems to surround the CDwin->Show();. if i switch it to ShowDialog(); it no longer is unresponsive, unfortunately the values of the progress bars do not update either, which i believe is where the multi-threading comes into play.

Comment: Did this compile?  `cooldowns ^ CDwin = gcnew cooldowns;` is not valid C++

Comment: visual studio 2012 compiled it without tossing any error or warnings

Comment: This looks like managed C++/CLI

Comment: I would just take out the sleep statement.  ASP.NET will fire an event when something happens... you don't wait for it.

Comment: i had the sleep in there because otherwise the progress bar would refresj so quickly that it flashes like its trying to give you a seizure, not sure if there is a better way to handle this.

Comment: There is no message loop in your code (`Form::ShowDialog` and `Application::Run` both contain one).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `ShowDialog` so your form has a message loop, and put your "every 50 ms" stuff in an event handler listening to your timer's `Tick` event.

Comment: thank you, I've changed it to ShowDialog, but now I am unable to complete tasks in the WinMain function, have I done something wrong or is this the way its supposed to work?

Comment: You are not supposed to do them in the WinMain function, only in your event handlers (or for long operations, in a separate thread). Note that for doing stuff on a separate thread, you can use the `ThreadPool` class's static methods.

Comment: so if i want to do work in the background that doesn't require user input to start/ have it continually looping i should create another thread before creating the form, process/collect the information i need, then pass the information back to the form?

Comment: Or use a timer control on the form, and each time this timer elapses, start a background task (with `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` or with `Task.Factory.StartNew` class) that passes its information back to the form when it ends (the form's `Invoke` method allows cross-thread calls to the form).

Comment: i wish i could +1 you, but unfortunately i will have to wait till i have reputation myself. but thank you for at least putting me on the track of where i should be looking.

Answer (score 0):

As the first form you should always use `System::Windows::Forms::Application::Run(CDwin)`, you can only use `Show()` and `ShowDialog()` methods when you already have run a form.

if you use `Run()` you will encounter some problems. This functions only returns something after form is closed that means codes after the `Run()` code will not be run until form is closed.

So you must forget about working with your form in main function. I recommend you to create two forms for example "Form1" and "Form2" (using threads is another way but this one's easier).

Use "Form1" as the base form that is hidden and it is used for updating the application by refreshing timer.

Use "Form2" as showed form to user. For doing this you should run "Form2" inside "Form1" using `Show()` or `ShowDialog()`.

So that means:

```
// This is Form1 or base.
#include "Form2.h"
Form2 ^openForm2 = gcnew Form2();
openForm2->Show();
// while(true) Refresh the other form and other codes...
```